# Cordova app store plugin errors in log

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I created an cordova app using ReactJS, webpack and only cordova. The app run ok, i tested it in my browser, the cordova browser and android devices and run ok in all. But in android i got the next errors in the log :

```
    D/SystemWebChromeClient: webpack:///./src/owl.carousel.js?: Line 1507 : Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1507)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined", source: webpack:///./src/owl.carousel.js? (1507)
D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryEntry.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryEntry.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryReader.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryReader.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Entry.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Entry.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/File.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/File.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileEntry.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileEntry.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileError.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileError.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileSystem.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileSystem.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileReader.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileReader.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadOptions.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadOptions.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadResult.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadResult.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Flags.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Flags.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/LocalFileSystem.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/LocalFileSystem.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Metadata.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Metadata.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/ProgressEvent.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/ProgressEvent.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/requestFileSystem.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/requestFileSystem.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystemPaths.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystemPaths.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems-roots.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems-roots.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/android/geolocation.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/android/geolocation.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/PositionError.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/PositionError.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/android/FileSystem.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/android/FileSystem.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/www/push.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/www/push.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/browser/isChrome.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: cordova.define is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/browser/isChrome.js (1)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1469 : Uncaught Error: Module cordova-plugin-device.device does not exist.
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1469)] "Uncaught Error: Module cordova-plugin-device.device does not exist.", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1469)
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1223 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1223)] "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1223)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1216 : Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1216)] "Channel not fired: onPluginsReady", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1216)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1216 : Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1216)] "Channel not fired: onCordovaReady", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1216)
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

If you check, the errors are about cordova plugins, the thing is some of these plugins i'm not using in the app and others (as the splash plugin) run ok without problem.

Why appear that errors? Sometimes in cordova's browser the error appear and the app doesn't run also, only in cordova browser.

**EDIT**
This is my index.js. With this file i call everything.

```
import Config from './elements/Config.js';
import Usuario              from './Clases/Usuario.jsx';

var Sesion = require('./elements/Sesion.jsx');
import Routes               from './Routes.jsx';
import Urls                from './elements/Urls.js';
import Rutas                from './elements/Rutas.jsx';
import {Router, Route, Link, DefaultRoute, IndexRoute, browserHistory}        from 'react-router'

window.reload = function (q) {

    if (!q) q = null
    window.location.href = '/index.html?q=' + q;
}

var app = {
    // Application Constructor

    initialize: function () {

        $('#spinner').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        var user = Sesion.obt('user');

        if (typeof user == 'object') {
            browserHistory.push(Rutas.urls.dashboard);
        }
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Routes/>,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );

    }

};

if (window.cordova) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        $("#root").before("cordova");
            app.initialize()

        }, false
    );
} else {
    app.initialize();
}
```

And this is what I include in my index.html file

```
    <div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/min/libreries.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dist/app/bundle.js"></script>
```

The bundle.js is the main file (index.js) with all logic after run webpack. the libreries.js have the next files :

- ReactJS
- React-dom
- jQuery

Comment: The first error is about jQuery, but is very strange, because the carousel run ok and jquery is loaded correctly.

Comment: Are you trying to use one of the plugins before the device is ready?

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel No. I edit the post adding my index.js before compiled it with webpack and the files that I include in the html file for more information, thanks for check it out.

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel no. I edited the post adding more information. My index.js file and the js includes in my index.html file. thanks for reading.